# contact-form: Template «» couln't be found

Tags: plugin-contactform

I'm trying to get [contact-form plugin](https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form) working.

When I add the default script and send the form I get this error:

[image]

```
craft\web\twig\TemplateLoaderException: The template «» couldn't be found. in /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/TemplateLoader.php:116
Stack trace:
#0 /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/TemplateLoader.php(72): craft\web\twig\TemplateLoader->_resolveTemplate('')
#1 /vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(299): craft\web\twig\TemplateLoader->getCacheKey('')
#2 /vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(381): Twig\Environment->getTemplateClass('')
#3 /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Environment.php(41): Twig\Environment->loadTemplate('', NULL)
#4 /vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(359): craft\web\twig\Environment->loadTemplate('')
#5 /vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(318): Twig\Environment->load('')
#6 /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(408): Twig\Environment->render('', Array)
#7 /vendor/hybridinteractive/craft-contact-form-extensions/src/ContactFormExtensions.php(157): craft\web\View->renderTemplate('', Array)
#8 [internal function]: hybridinteractive\contactformextensions\ContactFormExtensions->hybridinteractive\contactformextensions\{closure}(Object(craft\contactform\events\SendEvent))
#9 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Event.php(312): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(craft\contactform\events\SendEvent))
#10 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(642): yii\base\Event::trigger('craft\\contactfo...', 'beforeSend', Object(craft\contactform\events\SendEvent))
#11 /vendor/craftcms/contact-form/src/Mailer.php(102): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeSend', Object(craft\contactform\events\SendEvent))
#12 /vendor/craftcms/contact-form/src/controllers/SendController.php(54): craft\contactform\Mailer->send(Object(craft\contactform\models\Submission))
#13 [internal function]: craft\contactform\controllers\SendController->actionIndex()
#14 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(178): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#16 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(552): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#17 /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(293): yii\base\Module->runAction('contact-form/se...', Array)
#18 /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(602): craft\web\Application->runAction('contact-form/se...', Array)
#19 /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(272): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#20 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(384): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#21 /www/index.php(32): yii\base\Application->run()
#22 {main}
```

I use the regular unaltered script from the rpo:

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    {{ actionInput('contact-form/send') }}
    {{ redirectInput('contact/thanks') }}
```

what seems to be the issue here?

Craft: 3.7.63.1
php: 8.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere, somehow, you are trying to call a template named `«»`. That obviously doesn't exist.

Which means you need to track down *what* is trying to call that "template". It's very hard to say from here, the example form code that you included would not trigger that error on its own.

In your stack trace, on **line #7**, it seems that the `hybridinteractive/craft-contact-form-extensions` plugin is getting involved. Poke around the settings for that plugin, perhaps you'll find something.

Comment: YES. I found the issue. In the aforementioned `craft-contact-form-extensions` Plugin there needs to be a email template path specified, which I overlooked. Specifying a template solves the error. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Hi there! If you run into any other issues please feel free to create an issue on GitHub here https://github.com/hybridinteractive/craft-contact-form-extensions/issues and we'll be able to help you more there. Thanks for using our plugin and best of luck...